# Linear Discriminant Analysis Functions in R

Tags: r, classification, linear-discriminant

I have the following R code

```
ldf <- function(x, prior, mu, covar)
{
x <- matrix(as.numeric(diabetes), ncol=1)
log(lda.res$prior) - (0.5*t(lda.res$mean)%*%solve(cov_all)%*%lda.res$mean) + (t(x)%*%solve(covar)%*%mu)
}
```

I understand that the code is a function which will calculate the linear discriminant function.

However, I am unsure of what the following code is doing. It follows directly after the code above.

I know it is calculating the linear discriminant function for a patient but i'm not sure what each line means.

```
id <- 1 
dfs <- rep(0, G)
for(g in 1:G)
{
dfs[g] <- ldf(diabetes[id,2:4], lda.res$prior[g], lda.res$mean[g,], cov_all)
}
dfs
levels(diabetes$class)[dfs == max(dfs)]
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Where did you get code from if you don't know what it's doing? Does that source have any documentation?

Comment: Its part of code which came with an lda lecture. The data set is called 'diabetes'.